# Firebase child event listener not working well in Android service

Tags: android, firebase, service

I have a firebase child listener in an Android service. In **energy saving mode** (only), and when **app is in background**, the listener eventually **stop firing events** when data are added in firebase database.

I can't use FCM because I don't want OS notifications to appear in the system tray when app is in the background (that's what FCM does). The app will actually create notification on reception of those events, but those require app logic to bundle them ( https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html )

I'm using Android 7.0

**Any idea how to implement real-time listening with firebase when app is in background, that is resilient to energy-saving mode ?**